# Nearest Neighbor Two Point Tables Return Line Geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql, line, nearest-neighbor, knn

I am looking to find the nearest neighbor between two point tables in PostGIS and return the ids of both along with the line geometry. I have been able to determine the distance for the nearest between the two datasets but how do I return the line geometry.

```
select a.id, a._unique, closest_pt.dist
into nearest_neighbor_lines
from pois_1600 a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT
     id , 
     a.geom <-> b.geom as dist
     FROM intersections b
     ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom) AS closest_pt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `ST_MakeLine` the the initial and the closest point:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a._unique,
       closest_pt.dist,
       closest_pt.line_geom
INTO   nearest_neighbor_lines
FROM   pois_1600 AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT id,
         ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) AS line_geom,
         a.geom <-> b.geom AS dist
  FROM   intersections AS b
  ORDER BY
         a.geom <-> b.geom
  LIMIT  1
) AS closest_pt;
```

Note that you have to `LIMIT 1` in the join query to get only the one closest point each.

Comment: you are my PostGIS guru. Always coming thru in the clutch. Thanks again.